# Flutter ticker leaking for no reason

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, web

I am currently developing a flutter app using a library called `water_bottle` (https://pub.dev/packages/water_bottle) as an indicator for a liquid's level. The library requires me to provide a Global Key of type `WaterBottleState` in order to update the value and change the state.

```
class WaterState extends State<LifeWaterScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{
  final bottleReference = GlobalKey<WaterBottleState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    //...
    super.initState();
    setState(() {});
  }

  // build() method, etc...

  @override
  void dispose()
  {
    bottleReference.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I close (dispose) the current screen (using `Navigator.pop();` or the Android back button) an error is thrown telling me I did not dispose a `Ticker` properly.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
WaterBottleState#e8807(tickers: tracking 3 tickers) was disposed with an active Ticker.

WaterBottleState created a Ticker via its TickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. All Tickers must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.

The offending ticker was: _WidgetTicker(created by WaterBottleState#e8807)
The stack trace when the _WidgetTicker was actually created was:
#0      new Ticker.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:67:40)
#1      new Ticker (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:69:6)
#2      new _WidgetTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:385:81)
#3      TickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:295:34)
#4      new AnimationController (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:246:21)
#5      Bubble.randomize (package:water_bottle/src/bubble.dart:61:18)
#6      WaterContainer.initWater (package:water_bottle/src/waterContainer.dart:31:14)
#7      WaterBottleState.initState (package:water_bottle/src/waterBottle.dart:26:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4893:57)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (10 frames)
#19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#20     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#21     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
#40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#41     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#42     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
...     Normal element mounting (263 frames)
#305    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#306    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#307    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#308    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5845:32)
#309    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6445:17)
#310    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#311    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#312    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#313    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#314    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#315    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#316    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#317    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#318    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#319    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#320    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#321    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#322    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#323    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:11)
#324    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#325    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#326    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#327    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#328    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#329    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#330    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#331    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#332    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#333    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#334    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#335    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#336    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#337    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#338    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#339    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#340    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#341    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#342    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#343    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#344    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#345    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#346    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#347    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#348    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#352    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#353    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#354    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:342:13)
#1      TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:360:6)
#2      WaterBottleState.dispose (package:water_bottle/src/waterBottle.dart:35:11)
#3      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4983:11)
#4      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1926:13)
#5      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#7      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#8      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#9      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#10     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#11     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#12     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6386:16)
#13     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#14     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#15     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#16     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#17     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#18     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#19     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#20     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#21     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#22     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#23     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#24     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6386:16)
#25     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#26     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#27     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#28     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#29     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#30     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#31     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#32     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#33     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#34     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#35     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#37     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#38     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#39     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#40     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#41     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#43     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#44     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#45     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#46     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#47     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#48     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#49     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#50     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#51     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#52     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#53     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#54     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#55     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#56     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#57     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#58     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#59     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#60     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#61     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#62     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#63     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#64     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#65     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#66     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#67     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#68     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#69     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#70     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#71     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#72     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#73     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#74     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#75     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#76     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#77     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#78     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#79     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#80     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#81     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#82     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#83     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#84     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#85     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#86     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#87     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#88     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#89     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#90     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#91     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#92     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#93     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#94     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#95     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#96     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#97     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#98     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#99     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#100    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#101    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#102    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#103    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#104    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#105    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#106    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#107    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#108    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#109    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#110    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#111    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#112    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#113    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#114    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#115    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#116    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#117    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#118    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#119    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#120    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#121    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#122    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#123    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#124    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#125    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#126    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#127    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#128    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#129    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#130    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#131    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#132    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#133    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#134    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#135    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#136    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#137    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#138    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#139    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#140    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#141    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#142    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#143    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#144    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#145    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#146    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#147    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6271:14)
#148    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#149    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#150    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#151    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#152    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#153    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#154    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#155    _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1924:7)
#156    ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4807:14)
#157    _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1922:13)
#158    ListIterable.forEach (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:39:13)
#159    _InactiveElements._unmountAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1935:25)
#160    BuildOwner.lockState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2519:15)
#161    BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2932:7)
#162    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:19)
#163    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#164    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#165    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#166    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#170    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#171    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#172    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

The most weird part about this is that (from what I saw) the exception only occurs if the **value** had been **changed**:

```
bottleReference.currentState?.waterLevel = newValue;
```

As I am quite new to flutter I can't really tell if this is my or the library's fault as I'm actively disposing the state (`bottleReference.currentState?.dispose();`).
What I can tell is that the Ticker is apparently used by the library's bubble animation, but what has this to do with it's value?

As you can see I am very confused, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The error looks like it originates from the dispose method of `WaterBottleState` - Would you be able to share that code?

Comment: One thing you can check though, is simply to make sure that `super.dispose()` is the last line of code in the dispose method.

Comment: I am calling `super.dispose()` in the last line of the dispose method. You can find the sources for the library here: https://pub.dev/packages/water_bottle